# How to create data tables in an electron app

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, electron

I am creating an application with electron and I am trying to work with datatables with jquery.

but when I'm doing it in the html file and when i want to test it:

1 -> web page : it works in my browser 
2 -> electron app : it doesn't work and it shows only the table not the datatables features like search or others

how should i fix this problem ?

Comment: Completely unclear to me what you are asking. Post your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to install the datatable using NPM:

```
npm install --save datatables.net-dt
```

PS : make sure that the jquery is also installed in your node modules if not, use `npm install --save jquery` and add this code in your html page :

```
<script> window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery'); </script>
```

To be able to use the selected software in your package, use the following code:

```
require( 'datatables.net-dt' )();
```

now put the HTML table code and call the css file and the functionality of datatable with jquery in your html page:

HTML

```
<table id="table_id" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
```

Javascript

```
<script src="node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
      $('#table_id').DataTable();
  } );
</script>
```

source 
[Datatable download](https://datatables.net/download/)
[Datatable manual installation](https://datatables.net/manual/installation)